# Conflicting results using the same regex in text editor (Sublime Text) and online engine/tool (RegExr)

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am trying to learn the basics of regular expressions and am using my text editor (Sublime Text) and a website ([RegExr](https://regexr.com/)) to do so.

If I am correct, the expression `[H]ello` should only match the instances of hello starting with a capital H. This is the case when I use the above-mentioned website.

[image]

However, when I run the same query in the text editor, even the instances not starting with a capital H are matched.

[image]

The image below confirms that the regex [`H]ello` results in 8 matches and not 3.

[image]

Why am I getting different results in these two cases for such a simple regex? Also, any recommendations for tools/websites for learning regular expressions?

Comment: Though I have not used sublime, looks like your selection in the last screenshot, "Aa" - case sensitive should solve the issue. Try the search after selecting "Aa"

Comment: I agree that I can simply search for `Hello` by using the `Aa` (case sensitive) option. However, my aim is to learn how regular expressions work and what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What I meant in my comment was to tell Sublime text that you are applying the Regex in a case-sensitive manner and not searching "Hello" word completely.

[image]

**EDIT**:

Looks like Sublime text has issue with Regex and case-sensitivity check here https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1007

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But shouldn't `[H]` indicate upper-case H without selecting the `Aa` option. I guess, as your link suggests, this is an issue with the editor, which is very surprising given how widely it is used.

Comment: You are right if your purpose is just to learn RegEx, then [H]ello is correct, it's just that it is not working as expected in Sublime, which is an issue in the editor, but for learning purpose you can ignore it.